# string.replace generates function call error in c++

Tags: c++

trying to take a string and replace the lowercase letters to specific numbers (conversions apparent in code) using a while loop. string.replace gives an error "no matching member function for call to 'replace' :| been staring at the string.replace reference and can't see how my formatting is wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    // set variables

    string input_string;
    int string_length;
    bool isupper;
    bool isdig;
    int count;
    char current_var;
    string output_string;

    // Query user

    cout << "Welcome to Josh's Password Generator. Enter a password and I will convert it into numbers for entry in a touchtone phone." << endl;
    cin >> input_string;



    // calculations

    string_length = (int)input_string.length();
    count = 0;


    while(count <= string_length)

        if (input_string.at(count) == 'a' || input_string.at(count) == 'b' || input_string.at(count) == 'c')
    {
        current_var = 1;
    }
        else if (input_string.at(count) == 'd' || input_string.at(count) == 'e' || input_string.at(count) == 'f')
    {
       current_var = 2;
    }
    else if (input_string.at(count) == 'g' || input_string.at(count) == 'h' || input_string.at(count) == 'i')
    {
        current_var = 3;
    }
    else if (input_string.at(count) == 'j' || input_string.at(count) == 'k' || input_string.at(count) == 'l')
    {
        current_var = 4;
        }
        else if (input_string.at(count) == 'm' || input_string.at(count) == 'n' || input_string.at(count) == 'o')
        {
            current_var = 5;
        }
        else if (input_string.at(count) == 'p' || input_string.at(count) == 'q' || input_string.at(count) == 'r')
        {
            current_var = 6;
        }
        else if (input_string.at(count) == 's' || input_string.at(count) == 't' || input_string.at(count) == 'u')
        {
            current_var = 7;
        }
        else if (input_string.at(count) == 'v' || input_string.at(count) == 'w' || input_string.at(count) == 'x')
        {
            current_var = 8;
        }
        else if (input_string.at(count) == 'y' || input_string.at(count) == 'z')
        {
            current_var = 9;
        }
        else
            current_var = input_string.at(count);

        input_string = input_string.replace(count, current_var);

        count = count + 1;


    }
```

Comment: Apart for the fact that this code does not make a password less guessable, what you heard of either `maps` or `switch`?

Comment: `std::string::replace` is designed to substitute a substring with another string. Here, a simple `input_string[count] = current_var;` would suffice since you are only replacing a single character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace requires at least 3 arguments. Are you looking at the wrong [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/)?

You're missing the length argument, which indicates how many characters in the string are to be replaced. Try instead:

```
input_string.replace(count, 1, string(current_var));
```

One other note - 'using namespace std;' is [not advisable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).